# PHP - make paths relative when including file

Tags: php, include, relative-path

In a site root I have the following folders and files:

[image]

File includes/scripts.php includes links to all css/js files needed for the rest of the pages to function. When including scripts.php from any file in the site root (ex cart.php) all paths work fine. But when including from within a folder (ex. /admin) the paths are not correct, obviously because there isn't a /js or /css dir inside /admin.

I tried several things like changing the paths inside scripts.php from '../css/styles.css' to ./css/styles.css or just /css/styles.css but that didnt work. Also tried `include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "includes/scripts.php");` but also without success.

How do I make paths relative inside scripts.php so that no matter where it is included from, all css/js paths are correct and relevant to the site root?

This is an example of some linked files in scripts.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.alerts.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cookie.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css">
```

etc...

**EDIT:** I see that most of the answers have taken for granted that the files are hosted in a UNIX environment which is not true, it's being developed on a Windows/Apache setup and will be hosted on a UNIX server when finished. So I need a solution that works on both systems so I don't need to change the code whenever I'm editing/uploading the files to the live server.

Answer (score 6):

### Includes in PHP

#### Method 1 - using a constant

Create a constant (eg. `ROOTDIR`) in one of your root files (eg. index.php, or create a file that you always include relatively before any other include) before you include any other files:

```
//Place this in a file you always include relatively
define("ROOTDIR", dirname(__FILE__) . "/");
```

and wherever you include stuff:

```
//Place this in whatever file
require_once(ROOTDIR . "admin/panels/users.php");
```

---

#### Method 2 - using set_include_path

Alternatively, in the same file, instead of the constants, you could use [`set_include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) as such:

```
//Place this in a file you always include relatively
set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__) . "/");
```

and when you include stuff:

```
//Place this in whatever file
require_once("admin/panels/users.php");
```

---

#### Method 3 - through the PHP config

If you'd rather be without constants and `set_include_path` and have access to the PHP config file, you could also change [`include_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) in the config to eg. `/var/www/`, and then simply use above `require_once` when including files. [More info about that here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).

---

### But what about inclusion of scripts and stylesheets, h2ooooooo?

Well, I knew you'd get into that. What I usually tend to do is either make the path relative to root by starting it with an `/`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<!--                                ^                     -->
```

or you can alternatively set a [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Element/base) path in HTML:

```
<head>
    <base href="http://www.mydomain.com/" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

***Note:** When setting a `<base>` path, it also specified that all links will be relative to the base path as well so if you have a link in the admin folder pointing towards `subdir/` it will link to `http://www.mydomain.com/subdir/` and **not** `http://www.mydomain.com/admin/subdir/`.*

Comment: I think the problems here are the CSS/JS links in the html file that are not linked properly, not the inclusion of PHP files

Comment: @DamienLegros That may be - I've added an explanation for such as well.

Comment: Nice overview. Note that you need a leading `/` in method 1, like so: `define("ROOTDIR", dirname(__FILE__) . "/");` or `require_once(ROOTDIR . "/admin/panels/users.php");`.

Comment: @TaZ You're completely correct - I must be in dire need of some more coffee. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your solutions but i think they apply only to linux/unix servers and not a windows/apache configuration. With solutions 1&2 I'm getting the following warning: 

`include(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXXXX\includes/includes/scripts.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXXXX\index.php on line 26`

and with solutions 3&4 I have to change too many files and also change the base when I upload from testing (localhost) to live (webserver).

Comment: @bikey77 It seems you've used "includes" twice. Can we see your code, and which method you used?

Comment: I'll try to explain: each file includes /includes/data.php (at the very beginning) and then, before </head> tag I also include /includes/scripts.php.  Sο in data.php i've added `define("ROOTDIR", dirname(__FILE__) . "/");` and then in each file I include from within data.php or the rest of the files, I do it like this: `<? include(ROOTDIR .'includes/products.php'); ?>`

In all files where I include scripts.php I also do it like this: `<? include(ROOTDIR ."includes/scripts.php"); ?>`

Comment: @bikey77 In that case `dirname(__FILE__)` is pointing at your `includes/` directory already (`dirname(__FILE__)` points towards the folder of the file in which this command is run in). Hence, when including, simply use `include(ROOTDIR . scripts.php");`.

Comment: Ok, but what about the links to the css/js? How do I get them to always be relative?

Comment: @bikey77 By either using `<base>` or saving a constant with an absolute path `http://www.mydomain.com/` and refering to that.

Answer (score 1):

Please do the following changes instead of include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "includes/scripts.php");

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];?><js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];?>js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];?>js/jquery.alerts.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];?>js/cookie.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];?>css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];?>css/layout.css">
```

Comment: Thanks but your solution makes the links look like: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/js/backgroundScale.js missing the site root and making them inaccessible.

Comment: In local it will show the driver folder, but in server it similar to this path $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] => /var/services/web/mysite

Comment: I need a solution for the local machine as well, not only the server.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
Use the `base` tag in your html `<head>`, note: that will affect ALL the relative links

```
<base href="http://yoursite.com/" />
```

**Solution 2:**
Define an environment variable in your htaccess file

```
SetEnv MYSITE_URL http://yoursite.com/
```

and then in your html echo that environment variable

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo getenv('MYSITE_URL'); ?>js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo getenv('MYSITE_URL'); ?>js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
...
```

**Solution 3:**
Similar to solution 2 but instead create a php constant with your site url and echo it in your html

**Solution 4:**
Start your asset path with a `/`

Comment: I've tried Solution 4 but the links to assets are not correct if I include from files that are not in the root dir. Solutions 1&2 wont work on a windows machine. I'll give a go at solution 3 and let you know.

Comment: @bikey77 Solution 2 will work as long as you use apache (win or linux it doesn't matter)

Answer (score 0):

try using these function but you need to place it at the root folder on call it were you need it

```
function($_file){
php_uname();
$server_info = PHP_OS; // get host os info
$os = strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3));
if($os === 'WIN'){
    $path = dirname( $file );
    $p = explode(':',$path);
    return str_replace(array('\\','\\'), array('/','/'), $p[1]); //return the absolute path
}else{
    return dirname( $file );
}
}
```

example:

```
include get_path(__DIR__).path/to/asset/file.js
```